# Why is gprolog not responding as expected?

Tags: loops, prolog

I made a simple guess the number program and gprolog makes an infinite loop.But when I try it in strawberry prolog it doesn't!Why?

```
loop:-
   read(Guess),
   Guess \= 15,
   loop.
```

I also tried from rosettacode.

```
main :-
   random_between(1, 10, N),
   repeat,
   prompt1('Guess the number: '),
   read(N),
   writeln('Well guessed!'),
   !.
```

and it doesn't work in neither Strawberry or gprolog.

Why is this happening?

And what is the correct way to learn Prolog?

Comment: What did you type in? You need to make sure you put a period after the input (*e.g.*, `15.`). Exactly what are you seeing from Strawberry Prolog? In your second implementation, gprolog doesn't have a `random_between/3` predicate. I suspect Strawberry Prolog doesn't either. You need to check your prolog documentation.

Comment: I honestly did not know that a single full stop can make a huge difference.And strawberry prolog just opens a dialogue and you type in the guess and press enter without a full stop.Thank you though

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `read/1` it says it reads a Prolog *term*. On input, Prolog term must be delimited by a period. Strawberry Prolog is trying to be helpful from a GUI perspective. But overall, it's not a great Prolog implementation. You still need to avoid `random_between/3` unless you write it yourself.

Comment: I see.And i'm still very thankful,of your help and everything that you've done.